# how to read the output of a shell command

Tags: python

I am trying to run a shell script and depending on the output determine what is node-1 and node-2.
Currently I am able to get the desired output of the shell command,but not sure how to sort/read it and get the node names.

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["olsnodes", "-n"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
    print line
```

output:

```
vsin599   1

vsin600   2
```

I wanted to determine from the output the node names,like whatever is against the number 1 is node-1 and whatever is against number 2 is node-2..and so on if there is any other entry

Comment: If the node numbers are unique you can store them in a dictionary mapping node-number to node-name. What specifically are you struggling with? You've shown us some code that's working but not the code that's not working.

Comment: how do I convert the output into a dictionary format.

Comment: Are you simply needing a quick way to parse the output string? Try out: line.split()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment by Tom Dalton

```
d = {}
for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
    node,key = line.split(' ')
    d[int(key)] = node
```

Comment: when I say print(d)..it gives an empty dictionary { }

Comment: node,key = line.split(' ')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: changed to node,key = line.split()...and now I have the output in dictionary format as {1: 'vsin599', 2: 'vsin600'}

Comment: You have to pass a space inside split, not an empty string. line.split(' '). There is a space between two quotes. Get it ? Split(char) function takes the character inside it as a delimiter to split the string into list.